# C++ Output of a map with Pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, output

I'm trying to print the input in my map

```
map<string, Ort*> Hashtable;
```

The key is a string ( zipcode from a city)
The Objekt Ort* contains the name (string) and the x,y coords (double).

My try to print the map:

```
    for (it = Hashtable.begin(); it != Hashtable.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second->GetOrtsname()
                << " (" << it->second->GetPosX() << " " << it->second->GetPosY() << ")" << endl;
    }
```

The Error-Output:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Ort*>::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Ort*> >}’ and ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Ort*>::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Ort*> >}’)
             for (it = Hashtable.begin(); it != Hashtable.end(); it++) {
```

It seems like I'm to blind to really read the error-output
Thanks to juanchopanza

Solution:

```
map<string, Ort*>::const_iterator it;
```

Comment: You need to make `it` a `const_iterator`.

Comment: thanks a lot juanchpanza 
Could you perhaps explain why 'it' needs to be a const_iterator ?

Comment: Because you are map is `const`, or you are accessing it via a `const` reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are
>   ‘`std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Ort*>::iterator` {aka
>   `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Ort*>>}`’ and ‘`std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Ort*>::const_iterator` {aka `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, Ort*> >`}’)

refers to this statement:

```
it = Hashtable.begin()
```

and it is telling you there is no valid conversion between the type of the expression on the RHS of the `=` and the type of the LHS. The RHS is `...const_iterator`, the LHS is `....iterator`.

The reason for this is most likely that `Hashtable` is either a `const` map of a `const` reference to one. When calling the [`const` overload of `begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin), you get a `const_iterator`. This is the mechanism by which you are not allowed to modify the contents of a `const` map.